# By how much will the cost of petrol raise if the cost of petroleum raises by $10\%$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> At $22$ november $2012$ the price of petrol is given for the $35 \% $
>   by the cost of the product,which is formed by different things
>   (petroleum,refining,distributions costs,etc...);the price of petroleum
>   constitutes the $24 \%$ of the cost of the product.
>
> Given that  the first january $2013$ the price of petroleum will raise
>   by $10 \%$ and the other costs will not change,by how much will the
>   price of petrol raise in such date ?

**My effort**

Defining $O$ to be the price of petrol I have that $35 \% O=C$ ,where $C$ is the cost of the product.

I also have that $C=P+ \text{ rest}$ ,where I let $P$ be the price of petroleum and "$\text{rest}$" be the costs of the other voices of the product :refining,distribution costs ,etc..

Then it's given that $P=24 \% C$.

Now,recalling that $35 \% O=C$ I have that $P=24 \% (35 \% O)=8,4 \%O$

Solving for $O$ I have that $O=\cfrac{1}{8,4 \%}P\approx 1190 \% P$

Therefore I would expect that the new price of petrol,$O'$,is given by $O'=1190 \% (110 \%P
)$

To find the raise I simply calculate the difference $$O'-O=1190 \% (110 \%P
)-1190 \% P \approx 1,19 P =119 \% P$$ .

So my answer would be that the cost of petrol raises by $119 \%$  which is wrong as the solution is given to be $0,84 \%$

> **Question**
>
> Can somebody help me understand where I have made some mistakes  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, I think the problem formulation is not entirely clear. Given that the solution provided, one can deduce that it is asking for the new cost $O'$ assuming only the cost of petroleum changes and neither other costs nor the gross revenue are modified. This last part is crucial, because it means that after changing the cost of petroleum, the equation $C=35\% O'$ is no longer valid (this is what's causing the wrong answer in your deduction).

The TLDR answer is that, if the cost of petroleum increases by $10\%$, then that's the only thing we need to worry about: we have $P'=P+10\%P$, so the increase is $10\%P$, which is $10\% 8.4\%O = 0.84\% O$

Redoing the problem from scratch, we have:

$$ 
35\% O = C \\
24\% C = P \\
8.4\% O = P
$$

Now let's define:

$$ C = P + OtherCosts \\
O = C  + Revenue = P + OtherCosts + Revenue $$

So if the only thing that changes is $P$ to $P'$, then:

$$
O'=P'+OtherCosts+Revenue 
$$

Now, we know that $P$ increases $10\%$, so $P'= P+ 10\%P$. Replacing in the previous equation:

$$
O'=P'+OtherCosts+Revenue \\
O'=P + 10\%P +OtherCosts+Revenue  \\
O'=P  +OtherCosts+Revenue + 10\%P \\ 
O'= O + 10\%P 
$$

So now clearly:
$$
Increase = O'-O= O + 10\%P  - O= 10\%P
$$

But $10\%P=10\% 8.4\% O = 0.84\%O$. Therefore:
 $$Increase=0.84\%O$$

Comment: Thanks for all the commentary ,it has cleared every doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for simplicity that the cost of petrol is $100$. You have computed that $8.4$ is the cost of petroleum, plus $100 - 8.4 = 91.6$ other costs.

If the cost of petroleum increases by $10\%$, it goes from $8.4$ to $8.4 + 0.84$. So the total cost of petrol has increased by $0.84$.

---

In your notation, you have that $P = 8.4\% O = \dfrac{8.4}{100} O$. If $P$ increases by $10\%$, it increases of $\dfrac{0.84}{100} O = 0.84\% O$, and that's all the increase you have on $O$.

Comment: I am rather confused.Formally it would be that $110\%P=8,4\%O +0.84\% O$ but that's how much the cost of petroleum raises in terms of petrol not viceversa.What am I missing ?

Comment: I have tried to clarify.

Comment: But $0.84 \%$ is the raise of the cost of petroleum not petrol.Why is it equivalent ?

Comment: But you said that the rest does not increase.

Comment: And the way we have done it, the increase is measured as a percentage of the cost of petrol, which is what you want.